# setup.py won't catch the sphinx in the currently activated virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, setup.py, odoo-rpc

trying to build the docs for odoorpc 0.10.1

I checked out odoorpc to a local folder because the release available on Pypi is quite old

I installed it with

```
pip install ./
```

(./ is odoorpc)

According to the instructions I should

```
python setup.py build_doc
```

but I get

> No Sphinx module found. You have to install Sphinx to be able to
> generate the documentation.

But I swear that Sphinx is in the virtualenv

I'd like to be able to consult a recent revision of the docs

Answer (score 0):

Odoorpc `setup.py` checks for a module that was removed a while ago.  It needs to be fixed, but, in the meanwhile, the docs build fine by doing:

```bash
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -U sphinx

git clone https://github.com/OCA/odoorpc.git odoorpc
make -C odoorpc/doc html
```

It might be worth [creating an issue with odoorpc](https://github.com/OCA/odoorpc/issues) noting that they're relying on outdated functionality — or even a pull request if you fix it.  Specifically odoorpc's `setup.py` is looking for `sphinx.setup_command` which hasn't existed since April 2023, see Sphinx [issue 11363](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/11363).